# Like button increment counter not working. PHP, AJAX, MySQL, javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I am implementing a facebook like "Like" button counter so everytime a user clicks on the button, a DIV tag besides it retrieves it from the db and updates it (see logic of the code below). However it isn't working. Please see all codes below:-

javascript:

```
function likeAJAX(strName)
{
    If(strName == "")
    {
        document.getElementById('likeCount').innerHTML="";
        return;
    }
    else
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlHTTP = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        xmlHTTP = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    }
    xmlHTTP.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if(xmlHTTP.readystate == 4 && xmlHTTP.status == 200)
        {
            document.getElementById('likeCount').innerHTML = xmlHTTP.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlHTTP.open("GET","getLikes.php?n=" + strName,true);
    xmlHTTP.send();
}
```

HTML/PHP front-end:

```
<img src="./images/like.jpg" style="cursor:hand;" onclick="likeAJAX(<?php echo $_GET['val']; ?>)"><?php echo $likeVal; ?> people like this</span>
```

PHP/MySQL:

```
<?php
$q = $_GET['n'];
        $temp;
        $con = mysql_connect('localhost','xxxx','xxxx');
        mysql_select_db("xxxx");
        $SQLQuery = "SELECT * FROM likes where name= '" . $q . "'";
        $res = mysql_query($SQLQuery);
        while($data = mysql_fetch_array($res))
        {
            $temp = $data['likes'];
        }
        mysql_free_result($res);
        mysql_close($con);
        if($temp == "")
        {
            $temp = "0";
        }
        $intCount = int($temp);
        $intCount++;
        $con = mysql_connect('localhost','xxxx','xxxx');
        mysql_select_db("xxxx");
        $SQLQuery = "UPDATE likes set likes = '" . $intCount . "' WHERE busname = '". $q . "';";
        $res = mysql_query($SQLQuery);
        mysql_free_result($res);
        mysql_close($con);
        echo $intCount;
?>
```

Apologies for any formatting issues.
Where am i going wrong? The way i see it, seems like upon clicking the Like image, the javascript function doesn't even seems to be called?

Regards,

Ochen

Comment: I can see some issues with your `javascript`. First of all, `If` won't work, has to be `if`, no uppercase characters. Next, the first `else` statement should have `{ }` around it: `if(...){ } else { if(...){ else { } }`, for clarifications sake.

Answer (score 0):

Try this correction to your js:

```
function likeAJAX(strName) {
        if (strName == "") {
            document.getElementById('likeCount').innerHTML="";
            return;
        }  else {
            if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                xmlHTTP = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {
                xmlHTTP = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
            }
            xmlHTTP.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xmlHTTP.readystate == 4 && xmlHTTP.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById('likeCount').innerHTML = xmlHTTP.responseText;
                }
            }
            xmlHTTP.open("GET","getLikes.php?n=" + strName,true);
            xmlHTTP.send();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Pay attention to your call: onclick="likeAJAX(<?php echo $_GET['val']; ?>)">  try instead with: onclick="likeAJAX('<?php echo $_GET['val']; ?>')"  and let me know

Comment: am i supposed to be updating the DIV or the SPAN instead of just echoing?

Comment: $_GET['val'] means you are getting the value of the parameter url called just val. Can you check?

Comment: At this point point the problem is not a js problema but a php page problem. Where do you get the value to pass to the fuction? I checked the fuction as a js function and it runs correctly. Let me know more

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74203/discussion-between-gaemaf-and-ochen-jamir).

Comment: ok now i have added <div><?php echo $intCount; ?></div> to the getLikes.php and the conuter is incrementing but i don't see it until i refres the page .... !!!! seems like i am getting there but not just enough...!!!

Comment: Sorry, but it is necessary to avoid long discussion in comments: for last time: after the Ajax call you have to update your html.  Bye

Comment: can you please let me know how can that be done, i am almost there..?